# Bad request 400 error while sending digest authentication request using curl in php

Tags: php, curl, digest-authentication

I have been trying to send an authentication request via curl to an external server but it always returns bad requests. I have tried sending the request directly to the URL via postman and it works fine there.

Here is the code snippet I'm using

```
$request = sprintf('Authorization: Digest username="%s",realm="%s",nonce="%s",cnonce="%s",nc="%s",qop="%s",opaque="%s",uri="%s",response="%s"',
                $user, $response_realm, $response_nonce, $response_cnonce, $response_nc, $response_qop, $response_opaque, $loginURL, $authenticate_response);

$request_header = array($request);
$request_header[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Here is the curl info from the request

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://local-customer-manager.awlengine.com/api/v4/employee/auth/
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    [http_code] => 400
    [header_size] => 182
    [request_size] => 421
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.017697
    [namelookup_time] => 1.9E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.002964
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.013388
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 317
    [speed_download] => 18647
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 317
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.017688
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 13.78.113.193
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 10.0.0.10
    [local_port] => 37098
)
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with the code. I used the same logic in sending the request to retrieve the headers from the server and it worked perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So `$response_realm`, `$response_nonce` are values you got from the headers of the previous 401 response, or where do they come from?

Comment: @CBroe yes, I got them from the headers of the previous response

Comment: In theory you should not need to assemble the Authorization header yourself, cURL should be able to handle this, if you pass `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST` and the username & password via CURLOPT_USERPWD, have you given that a try yet? https://stackoverflow.com/q/13026725/1427878

Comment: Yeah I tried that method before but it gave a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the "400 Bad Request" error too and when I'd comment out just the `Authorization` header, it was resolved so that pin-pointed me to really scrutinizing how I formatted it.

This is the format that finally worked for me:

```
// Digest Authentication
$digest_auth_header = sprintf(
    'Digest username="%s",realm="%s",nonce="%s",cnonce="%s",nc="%s",qop="%s",opaque="%s",uri="%s",response="%s"',
    $username, // username, supplied
    $realm, // realm, same as server response
    $nonce, // nonce, same as server response - generated by other site to return back as is
    $cnonce, // cnonce, random unique ID generated by client
    $nc, // nonce-count, hexadecimal serial number for the request, the client should increase this number by one for every request
    $qop, // qop, values are "auth" or "auth-in"
    $opaque, // opaque, same as server response
    $request_uri, // uri - authentication uri
    $response // response, validation hash
);
```

Of course, `Authentication` wasn't my only header. I was sending a `POST`